# How do I find the first integral of this second order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So i'm already given that $G=\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert$ (Euclidean norm) which is therefore just $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$  . So here $G$ is a  first integral.

And given $\ddot{x}+\mu(x^2-1)\dot{x}+x=0$  for $\mu > 0$ , I'm trying to find for what values of $\mu$ would this first integral be satisfied.

Now what I'm confused about is how to actually work out the first integral from this 2nd order ODE, only then can I see what kind of value (perhaps none) of $\mu$ would satisfy this G.

Some help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check under "Van der Pol oscillator", "fast-slow systems", "canards". For instance in http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Canards

Answer (score 1):

Hint: rewrite the system putting $y = \dot{x}$, that is
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = y \\
\dot{y} = -x-\mu (x^2-1)y.
\end{cases}
$$
Hence 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2) & = 2x\dot{x}+2y\dot{y} \\
& = -2\mu y^2(x^2-1).
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand this part:  d/dt(x^2+y^2). I'm assuming whats on the right is chain rule.

Comment: Yes it is: consider the functions $f(t)=x(t)$ and $g(y)=y^2$. Then $g(f(t)) = x^2(t)$ and by the chain rule you have $(g\circ f)'(t)=g'(f(t))f'(t)=2x(t)x'(t)=2x\dot{x}$.